# Configure read timeout OpenSearch client

Tags: java, spring, opensearch

I don't find in documentation how to configure read timeout on an opensearch RestHighLevelClient

```
final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
            credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
            RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                            new HttpHost(url, port, scheme))
                    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder
                            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));
            return new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
.setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder.setSocketTimeout(10000))
```